# sshtuinnel improperly installed?

Tags: python, pip, ssh-tunnel

Not sure where I'm going wrong, just know this has all been harder then I'd of thought.  Trying to connect to a MySQL database on a raspberry pi from another...

If I do 'pip list' I see sshtunnel (0.1.3) is installed.

Trying to execute:

```
import sshtunnel
```

yields the following error...

```
>>> import sshtunnel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "sshtunnel.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
ImportError: cannot import name SSHTunnelForwarder
```

In the script I'm really trying to do

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
```

but getting pretty much the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sshtunnel.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
  File "/home/pi/sshtunnel.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
```

Hoping this is my final(and easily solvable) hurdle!

Regards,
Matt

Comment: You shouldn't be naming your script sshtunnel.py that will override the sshtunnel in your module library.

Comment: Thanks...new to this.  :)